# Read Excel named range from C#

Tags: c#, excel, range, oledb

I am trying to read a named range from my excel as per below:

```
    conn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [NamedRange]"))
        {
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            //conn.Open();
            var result = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (result.Read())
            {
                var str = result[0].ToString();
            }

        }
```

The code runs but the while loop gets skipped. I know my named range should be read because this method works:

```
 OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [NamedRange]”, conn);
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    da2.Fill(dt2);

foreach (DataColumn Col in dt2.Columns)
                    {var str = Col.Caption}
```

I cannot figure out why the first method does not work.

Comment: Your second SQL is different from the first?

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry it should be the same

Comment: @user8608110 Can you please re-test your updated code on your end, this time taking note of the *specifics* about the error you're getting (when, where, what have you tried) and [edit] your question to provide more information and background.  See [mcve] and well as the [help/on-topic] and also "[ask]"

Comment: There is no error - the first method just does not read anything

Comment: @user8608110 What is your conn? Please post the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is still looking for a solution, change your query like this:

`OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [sheetName$][NamedRange]")`

I hope this helps!